# Redux Saga class generators

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, generator, redux-saga

New to this concept and setup so I'm sorry in advance for my vage description!

I'm trying to create reusable sagas for different modules I have. The issue I'm having is `this` seems to be out of concept in the generator function within the class so am I right in thinking that this function is being called statically?

Does anyone have any idea of how I can achieve this kind of structure? Basically what I want to do is call a function where I can manipulate the url variable and an object called config which changes per extend. I've come from a PHP background so I have this idea of extending an Abstract class.

```
export default class Saga {
    config = {};
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    * paginationAsync()
        while(true) {
            const action = yield effects.take(this.config.PAGINATION_ASYNC);
            const url = yield effects.call(this.generatePaginationUrl, action);
            //this.config = "Cannot read property 'config' of null"

            //Continue with stuff here 

        }
    }
}
```

**Using the above class**

```
import Saga from './Saga';
import {effects} from 'redux-saga';
import * as config from './config';

class SalonSagas extends Saga {
    generatePaginationUrl(action) {
        return 'salons/';
    }
}

export default function* saga()
{

    const sagas = new SalonSagas(config);

    effects.all([
        effects.fork(sagas.paginationAsync),
    ]);
}
```

Previous I used this setup. I'm trying to avoid copying and pasting this function for every instance I want to use this method.

```
function* pagintationAsnyc()
    while(true) {
        const action = yield effects.take(config.PAGINATION_ASYNC);
        const auth = yield effects.select((state) => state.auth);

        //generic action

        const response = yield effects.call(api.get, '/salons', {'Authorisation': 'Bearer '+auth.token});

        //do more generic actions I'm trying to prevent copying and pasting

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool here.  Instead of a class, you should use a function that returns a function (frequently known as a "factory function" or a "higher-order function".  Quick example:

```
function createPaginationSaga(config) {
    return function* paginationAsync() {
        while(true) {
            const action = yield effects.take(config.PAGINATION_ASYNC);
            const url = yield effects.call(generatePaginationUrl, action);
            //Continue with stuff here 

        }
    }
}
```

For that matter, I believe you can actually reuse the `paginationAsync` function directly, like:

```
export default function* saga() {
    yield effects.all([
        effects.fork(paginationAsync, config),
    ]);
}
```

That would require declaring it as `function* paginationAsync(config)`, and it should receive the config value as a parameter.

Comment: thanks! I shall give that a go! I did try `effects.fork(paginationAsync(config))` and that failed so I gave up with that idea then did think maybe I could do something in in saga function but wasn't sure! Thanks again!